# I have a problem in looping the simulation with different variable

Tags: c++, ns-3

I have a little problem where I cant loop the simulation as I need to change the variable a few times. I'm currently trying to loop the examples from the NS3 mmwave epc tdma with different data rates for the link. Can anyone guide me through this? Your help will be very much appreciated. I have snippet my code below for you guys to comment

```
#include "ns3/mmwave-helper.h"
#include "ns3/epc-helper.h"
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/ipv4-global-routing-helper.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"
#include "ns3/point-to-point-helper.h"
#include "ns3/config-store.h"
#include "ns3/mmwave-point-to-point-epc-helper.h"
#include "ns3/rng-seed-manager.h"
//#include "ns3/gtk-config-store.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "ns3/netanim-module.h"
#include "ns3/log.h"
#include "ns3/flow-monitor-module.h"

using namespace ns3;
using namespace mmwave;

/**
 * It instantiates several eNodeB,
 * attaches one UE per eNodeB starts a flow for each UE to  and from a remote host.
 * It also  starts yet another flow between each UE pair.
 */
NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE ("MmWaveEpcTdma");
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //LogComponentEnable ("LteUeRrc", LOG_LEVEL_ALL);
    //LogComponentEnable ("LteEnbRrc", LOG_LEVEL_ALL);
    //    LogComponentEnable("mmWavePointToPointEpcHelper",LOG_LEVEL_ALL);
    //    LogComponentEnable("EpcUeNas",LOG_LEVEL_ALL);
//        LogComponentEnable ("MmWaveSpectrumPhy", LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
//    LogComponentEnable ("MmWaveBeamforming", LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
//    LogComponentEnable ("MmWaveUePhy", LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
//    LogComponentEnable ("MmWaveEnbPhy", LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG); //
//    LogComponentEnable ("MmWaveFlexTtiMacScheduler", LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
//    LogComponentEnable ("MmWaveFlexTtiMaxWeightMacScheduler", LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
    //LogComponentEnable ("OnOffApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
//    LogComponentEnable ("LteRlcAm", LOG_LEVEL_LOGIC);
    //LogComponentEnable ("LteRlcUm", LOG_LEVEL_LOGIC);
    //LogComponentEnable ("MmWaveUeMac", LOG_LEVEL_LOGIC);
    //LogComponentEnable ("UdpClient", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
//    LogComponentEnable ("TcpClient", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
    //LogComponentEnable ("PacketSink", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
    //LogComponentEnable("PropagationLossModel",LOG_LEVEL_ALL);
    double ULdataRateMB = 900e6;  // 100 Mbps
    double DLdataRateMB = 100e6;  // 100 Mbps
//    int ta = 1;
for (int ta = 1; ta < 11; ta++)

    {
    uint16_t numEnb = 1;
    uint16_t numUe = 1;
    double simTime = 5.0;  //5.0
    double interPacketInterval = 100;  // 500 microseconds
    double minDistance = 10.0;  // eNB-UE distance in meters
    double maxDistance = 200.0;  // eNB-UE distance in meters
    bool harqEnabled = true;
    bool rlcAmEnabled = false; //false
    bool fixedTti = false;
    unsigned symPerSf = 14;
    double sfPeriod = 1000.0;
    unsigned run = 0;


    // Command line arguments
    CommandLine cmd;
    cmd.AddValue("numEnb", "Number of eNBs", numEnb);
    cmd.AddValue("numUe", "Number of UEs per eNB", numUe);
    cmd.AddValue("simTime", "Total duration of the simulation [s])", simTime);
    cmd.AddValue("interPacketInterval", "Inter-packet interval [us])", interPacketInterval);
    cmd.AddValue("harq", "Enable Hybrid ARQ", harqEnabled);
    cmd.AddValue("rlcAm", "Enable RLC-AM", rlcAmEnabled);
    cmd.AddValue("symPerSf", "OFDM symbols per subframe", symPerSf);
    cmd.AddValue("sfPeriod", "Subframe period = 4.16 * symPerSf", sfPeriod);
    cmd.AddValue("fixedTti", "Fixed TTI scheduler", fixedTti);
    cmd.AddValue("run", "run for RNG (for generating different deterministic sequences for different drops)", fixedTti);
    cmd.Parse(argc, argv);

    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWaveHelper::RlcAmEnabled", BooleanValue(rlcAmEnabled));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWaveHelper::HarqEnabled", BooleanValue(harqEnabled));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWaveFlexTtiMacScheduler::HarqEnabled", BooleanValue(harqEnabled));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWaveFlexTtiMaxWeightMacScheduler::HarqEnabled", BooleanValue(harqEnabled));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWaveFlexTtiMaxWeightMacScheduler::FixedTti", BooleanValue(fixedTti));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWaveFlexTtiMaxWeightMacScheduler::SymPerSlot", UintegerValue(6));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWavePhyMacCommon::ResourceBlockNum", UintegerValue(1));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWavePhyMacCommon::ChunkPerRB", UintegerValue(72));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWavePhyMacCommon::SymbolsPerSubframe", UintegerValue(symPerSf));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWavePhyMacCommon::SubframePeriod", DoubleValue(sfPeriod));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWavePhyMacCommon::TbDecodeLatency", UintegerValue(200.0));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWaveBeamforming::LongTermUpdatePeriod", TimeValue (MilliSeconds (100000.0)));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::LteEnbRrc::SystemInformationPeriodicity", TimeValue (MilliSeconds (5.0)));
    //Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWavePropagationLossModel::ChannelStates", StringValue ("n"));////////////////////////////////////////////////can be comment
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::LteRlcAm::ReportBufferStatusTimer", TimeValue(MicroSeconds(100.0)));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::LteRlcUmLowLat::ReportBufferStatusTimer", TimeValue(MicroSeconds(100.0)));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::LteEnbRrc::SrsPeriodicity", UintegerValue (320));
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::LteEnbRrc::FirstSibTime", UintegerValue (2));

    // the applications on this example start very early.
    // Use the IDEAL mode in RRC (no radio messages are exchanged for RRC control ops)
    // and set to the minimum the latency on the S1-AP link to speed up the link and bearers setup
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWaveHelper::UseIdealRrc", BooleanValue(false)); //false
    Config::SetDefault ("ns3::MmWavePointToPointEpcHelper::S1apLinkDelay", TimeValue(Seconds(0)));

    RngSeedManager::SetSeed (1234);
    RngSeedManager::SetRun (run);

    Ptr<MmWaveHelper> mmwaveHelper = CreateObject<MmWaveHelper> ();
    mmwaveHelper->SetSchedulerType ("ns3::MmWaveFlexTtiMaxWeightMacScheduler");
    //mmwaveHelper->SetSchedulerType ("ns3::MmWaveFlexTtiMacScheduler");
    Ptr<MmWavePointToPointEpcHelper>  epcHelper = CreateObject<MmWavePointToPointEpcHelper> ();
    mmwaveHelper->SetEpcHelper (epcHelper);
    mmwaveHelper->SetHarqEnabled (harqEnabled);

    ConfigStore inputConfig;
    inputConfig.ConfigureDefaults();

    // parse again so you can override default values from the command line
    cmd.Parse(argc, argv);

    Ptr<Node> pgw = epcHelper->GetPgwNode ();

    // Create a single RemoteHost
    NodeContainer remoteHostContainer;
    remoteHostContainer.Create (1);
    Ptr<Node> remoteHost = remoteHostContainer.Get (0);
    InternetStackHelper internet;
    internet.Install (remoteHostContainer);

    // Create the Internet
    PointToPointHelper p2ph;
    p2ph.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", DataRateValue (DataRate ("10Gb/s")));
    p2ph.SetDeviceAttribute ("Mtu", UintegerValue (1500));
    p2ph.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", TimeValue (MicroSeconds (100.0)));
    NetDeviceContainer internetDevices = p2ph.Install (pgw, remoteHost);
    Ipv4AddressHelper ipv4h;
    ipv4h.SetBase ("1.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0");
    Ipv4InterfaceContainer internetIpIfaces = ipv4h.Assign (internetDevices);
    // interface 0 is localhost, 1 is the p2p device
    Ipv4Address remoteHostAddr = internetIpIfaces.GetAddress (1);

    Ipv4StaticRoutingHelper ipv4RoutingHelper;
    Ptr<Ipv4StaticRouting> remoteHostStaticRouting = ipv4RoutingHelper.GetStaticRouting (remoteHost->GetObject<Ipv4> ());
    remoteHostStaticRouting->AddNetworkRouteTo (Ipv4Address ("7.0.0.0"), Ipv4Mask ("255.0.0.0"), 1);

    NodeContainer ueNodes;
    NodeContainer enbNodes;
    enbNodes.Create(numEnb);
    ueNodes.Create(numUe);

    // Install Mobility Model
    Ptr<ListPositionAllocator> enbPositionAlloc = CreateObject<ListPositionAllocator> ();
    enbPositionAlloc->Add (Vector (0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    MobilityHelper enbmobility;
    enbmobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
    enbmobility.SetPositionAllocator(enbPositionAlloc);
    enbmobility.Install (enbNodes);

    MobilityHelper uemobility;
    Ptr<ListPositionAllocator> uePositionAlloc = CreateObject<ListPositionAllocator> ();
    Ptr<UniformRandomVariable> distRv = CreateObject<UniformRandomVariable> ();

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < numUe; i++)
    {
        double dist = distRv->GetValue (minDistance, maxDistance);
        uePositionAlloc->Add (Vector (dist, 0.0, 0.0));
    }
    uemobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
    uemobility.SetPositionAllocator(uePositionAlloc);
    uemobility.Install (ueNodes);

    // Install mmWave Devices to the nodes
    NetDeviceContainer enbmmWaveDevs = mmwaveHelper->InstallEnbDevice (enbNodes);
    NetDeviceContainer uemmWaveDevs = mmwaveHelper->InstallUeDevice (ueNodes);

    // Install the IP stack on the UEs
    internet.Install (ueNodes);
    Ipv4InterfaceContainer ueIpIface;
    ueIpIface = epcHelper->AssignUeIpv4Address (NetDeviceContainer (uemmWaveDevs));
    // Assign IP address to UEs, and install applications
    for (uint32_t u = 0; u < ueNodes.GetN (); ++u)
    {
        Ptr<Node> ueNode = ueNodes.Get (u);
        // Set the default gateway for the UE
        Ptr<Ipv4StaticRouting> ueStaticRouting = ipv4RoutingHelper.GetStaticRouting (ueNode->GetObject<Ipv4> ());
        ueStaticRouting->SetDefaultRoute (epcHelper->GetUeDefaultGatewayAddress (), 1);
    }

    mmwaveHelper->AttachToClosestEnb (uemmWaveDevs, enbmmWaveDevs);

    // Install and start applications on UEs and remote host
    uint16_t dlPort = 1234;
    uint16_t ulPort = 2000;
    uint16_t otherPort = 3000;
    ApplicationContainer clientApps;
    ApplicationContainer serverApps;
    uint32_t packetSize = 1400;
    double onTimeSec = 5e-6; // packetSize / dataRateMB;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "ns3::ConstantRandomVariable[Constant=" << onTimeSec << "]";
    std::cout << "OnTime == " << ss.str() << std::endl;
    OnOffHelper dlClient ("ns3::UdpSocketFactory", InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), dlPort));
    OnOffHelper ulClient ("ns3::UdpSocketFactory", InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), ulPort));
    dlClient.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue (packetSize));
    ulClient.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue (packetSize));
    dlClient.SetAttribute ("DataRate", DataRateValue (8*DLdataRateMB));
    ulClient.SetAttribute ("DataRate", DataRateValue (8*ULdataRateMB));
    dlClient.SetAttribute ("OnTime", StringValue (ss.str ()));
    ulClient.SetAttribute ("OnTime", StringValue (ss.str ()));
    ss.str("");
    ss << "ns3::ExponentialRandomVariable[Mean=" << interPacketInterval*1e-6 << "]";
    std::cout << "OffTime == " << ss.str() << std::endl;
    dlClient.SetAttribute ("OffTime", StringValue (ss.str ()));
    ulClient.SetAttribute ("OffTime", StringValue (ss.str ()));

    for (uint32_t u = 0; u < ueNodes.GetN (); ++u)
    {
        ++ulPort;
        ++otherPort;
        PacketSinkHelper dlPacketSinkHelper ("ns3::UdpSocketFactory", InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), dlPort));
        PacketSinkHelper ulPacketSinkHelper ("ns3::UdpSocketFactory", InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), ulPort));
        serverApps.Add (dlPacketSinkHelper.Install (ueNodes.Get(u)));
        serverApps.Add (ulPacketSinkHelper.Install (remoteHost));

        // UdpClientHelper dlClient (ueIpIface.GetAddress (u), dlPort);
        // dlClient.SetAttribute ("Interval", TimeValue (MicroSeconds(interPacketInterval)));
        // dlClient.SetAttribute ("MaxPackets", UintegerValue(1000000));
        // dlClient.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue(packetSize));

        // UdpClientHelper ulClient (remoteHostAddr, ulPort);
         // ulClient.SetAttribute ("Interval", TimeValue (MicroSeconds(interPacketInterval)));
        // ulClient.SetAttribute ("MaxPackets", UintegerValue(1000000));
        // ulClient.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue(packetSize));

        UdpClientHelper client (ueIpIface.GetAddress (u), otherPort);
        client.SetAttribute ("Interval", TimeValue (MicroSeconds(interPacketInterval)));
        client.SetAttribute ("MaxPackets", UintegerValue(1000000));
        dlClient.SetAttribute ("Remote", AddressValue (InetSocketAddress (ueIpIface.GetAddress (u), dlPort)));
        ulClient.SetAttribute ("Remote", AddressValue (InetSocketAddress (remoteHostAddr, ulPort)));

        clientApps.Add (dlClient.Install (remoteHost));
        clientApps.Add (ulClient.Install (ueNodes.Get(u)));
        if (u+1 < ueNodes.GetN ())
        {
            clientApps.Add (client.Install (ueNodes.Get(u+1)));
        }
        else
        {
            clientApps.Add (client.Install (ueNodes.Get(0)));
        }
    }
    serverApps.Start (Seconds (0.003));
    clientApps.Start (Seconds (0.003));
    mmwaveHelper->EnableTraces ();


    // 8. Install FlowMonitor on all nodes
  //FlowMonitorHelper flowmon;
  //Ptr<FlowMonitor> monitor = flowmon.InstallAll ();

    Ptr <FlowMonitor> monitor;
    FlowMonitorHelper flowmon;
    monitor = flowmon.Install (ueNodes);
    monitor = flowmon.Install (remoteHostContainer);

    // Uncomment to enable PCAP tracing
    std::string s = "caseUDP Bi-directional Adjusted Case"+ std::to_string(ta);
     p2ph.EnablePcapAll(s);
    AnimationInterface anim("animcaseUDP02TrialBidirectional");
    Simulator::Stop(Seconds(simTime));
    Simulator::Run();

    //flow monitor
  monitor->CheckForLostPackets ();
  Ptr<Ipv4FlowClassifier> classifier = DynamicCast<Ipv4FlowClassifier> (flowmon.GetClassifier ());
  std::map<FlowId, FlowMonitor::FlowStats> stats = monitor->GetFlowStats ();
  for (std::map<FlowId, FlowMonitor::FlowStats>::const_iterator i = stats.begin (); i != stats.end (); ++i)
    {
      if (i->first > 0)
        {
          Ipv4FlowClassifier::FiveTuple t = classifier->FindFlow (i->first);
          std::cout << "Flow " << i->first - 0 << " (" << t.sourceAddress << " -> " << t.destinationAddress << ")\n";
          std::cout << "  Tx Bytes:   " << i->second.txBytes << "\n";
          std::cout << "  Rx Bytes:   " << i->second.rxBytes << "\n";
          std::cout << "  Tx Packets:   " << i->second.txPackets << "\n";
          std::cout << "  Rx Packets:   " << i->second.rxPackets << "\n";
          std::cout << "  Lost Packets:   " << i->second.txPackets - i->second.rxPackets << "\n";
          std::cout << "  Throughput:   " << (i->second.txBytes - i->second.rxBytes)* 8.0 / 10.0 / 1000 / 1000  << " Mbytes\n";
          std::cout << "  Times Forwarded:   " << float(i->second.timesForwarded) << "\n";
          std::cout << "  Mean Hop Count:   " << float(i->second.timesForwarded) /  (i->second.txBytes - i->second.rxBytes)  + 1 << "\n";
          std::cout << "  Mean Delay:   " << i->second.delaySum.GetSeconds() / (i->second.txBytes - i->second.rxBytes) << "\n";
          std::cout << "  Sum Delay:   " << i->second.delaySum.GetSeconds() << "\n";
          std::cout << "  Mean Jitter:   " << i->second.jitterSum.GetSeconds() / (i->second.rxPackets-1)<< "\n";
          std::cout << "  Last Delay:   " << i->second.lastDelay.GetSeconds() << "\n";
          std::cout << "  Throughput: " << i->second.rxBytes * 8.0 / 10.0 / 1000 / 1000  << " Mbytes\n";
          std::cout << "  Delay Histogram:   " << i->second.delayHistogram.GetNBins ()  << "\n";
          std::cout << "  Jitter Histogram:   " << i->second.jitterHistogram.GetNBins ()  << "\n";
          std::cout << "  Packet Size Histogram:   " << i->second.packetSizeHistogram.GetNBins ()  << "\n";
          std::cout << "  Flow Interruptions Histogram:   " << i->second.flowInterruptionsHistogram.GetNBins ()  << "\n";            
        }
    }
    /*GtkConfigStore config;
  config.ConfigureAttributes();*/

    ULdataRateMB=ULdataRateMB-100e6;
    DLdataRateMB=DLdataRateMB+100e6;
    return ULdataRateMB;
    return DLdataRateMB;
    // return 0;
    Simulator::Destroy();
}}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: Which variable is *the* variable, and what is the problem with changing it?

Comment: The code could need some restructuring, making it a class or at least sub routines.

Comment: I suggest you split this huge question into smaller questions and ask for the single calls you do not understand. It will help to give you a concise answer to your questions.

Comment: I don’t understand what do you want to achieve with the very first for loop? If I’m not wrong, you’re trying to iterate over the whole main body. Ns3 doesn’t work like that. Try to edit your question, I will catch you later.